# add #ajax property to email field in node add form usion hook_form_alter

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I've tried to add the property "#ajax" to email field but It dosen't work, 
I've tried all this :

```
$form["field_user_email"]['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'user_ajax_check',
      'wrapper' => 'usercheck',
      'effect' => 'fade',
  );

$form["field_user_email"]['und']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'user_ajax_check',
      'wrapper' => 'usercheck',
      'effect' => 'fade',
  );
$form["field_user_email"]['und'][0]['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'user_ajax_check',
      'wrapper' => 'usercheck',
      'effect' => 'fade',
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the field is provided by the [Email Field](http://drupal.org/project/email) module it'll probably be:

```
$form["field_user_email"]['und'][0]['email']['#ajax'] = array(...
```

If it's just a standard text field it will be:

```
$form["field_user_email"]['und'][0]['value']['#ajax'] = array(...
```

Comment: It's working now I can see the ajax , but when it performed I have lot of missing form element , can you help please , you are a life saver

Comment: I'd guess it's something to do with the AJAX wrapper, and the element you're actually wrapping (you're probably wrapping the whole field array and not just the individual element). Can you post your AJAX callback code along with the code you're using now in the form alter function, either in your question or a new one (new one would probably be better, it would separate the things out so it's more helpful fo future users)?

Comment: thanx that helped me a lot

Comment: I create a field in article content type,it's type is text ,I really test all of above methods in mycustommodule_form_alter, really not working for me.but my method work correctly. :(